# What is the code?

Tags: riddle, cipher

You have a digital safe you need to unlock, but you forgot the 5 digit code.

Luckily, your friend, Ben Dover knows what the code is. But he won't just tell you, he gave you a single clue to start off with. And that clue is...

"Juicy boi you just need to find the **location** *wink wink* of the answer..."

You ask Ben Dover, "Location? Seriously, what is that supposed to mean?"

He replies, "If my *about me* section of my Puzzling account said anything about it, I'm sure, it'd give you the answer."

"What!? Your About Me section doesn't make any sense! The youtube page that you put on there doesn't send me anywhere!"

As you start to walk away, you wonder if the location and the youtube web page have anything in common...

What is the code?

Hint: think WAY outside the box.

Comment: Hello Ben Dover :D **Edit:** Sounds like *bend over* hehehe...

Comment: As much as I like this puzzle, unless the expected solution has some solid reasoning that all the below answers aren't acceptable (which it absolutely could do) - I'd suggest this is too broad (and effectively breaks down to "guess a code that has *some* vague relation to the question, and see if it's the one OP was thinking of")

Comment: @Bilkokuya yes, I agree. An answer has been accepted now, but I see no reason that makes _that_ answer the "correct" one. Jamie Barker's answer makes sense to me, and so does user477343's.

Comment: Look, I like making difficult riddles. But I didn't know I was making them too difficult, Which is probably why my first two riddles I created were put on hold. But if a moderator or person with 3000 rep sees this, please consider putting me off hold. I added way more details and hints to give people solving this an easier time. Thanks!

Comment: It's not that they're too difficult, it's that as written, there are too many valid answers that it just becomes a question of which one was the particular one you were thinking of. It stops being a riddle and just becomes a creative guessing game.

Comment: It isn't a guessing riddle... You'll find out if you try your best to actually solve the riddle with the details and clues given.

Answer (score 27):

The code is

> 72254

Because

> the location of *this* answer is https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/72254/

Comment: Oh, no way! I even saw that edit! Hahaah, you got this, I bet :D

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's the wrong answer XD, this is the answer I'll accept any day

Comment: Sorry that this is the wrong answer... But I fixed the question to give more hints. Maybe that'll help you.

Comment: @BenDover this was wrong?

Comment: Hereis the youtube page if you can't find it... it just says video unavaible though https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5CpilKADZd

Answer (score 7):

Is the code

> **DIGIT**?

`"Juicy boi you just need to find the *location* of the answer..."`

> Well, the answer is located on a **digital** safe.

Also,

> The code is $5$ letters, and although they are not digits, the code is **digit**al.

**Hint:**

`think WAY outside the box`

> It is outside the box because the code does not contain any actual digits.

Also,

> An anagram of "outside the box" is "outboxed heist" so I believe you want to steal the contents in this safe, where the digits refer to **money**? Hence the safe is not actually digital, but like a box.

Answer (score 3):

Is the code:

> 31022

Because:

> That's the population of Dover according to Google

Comment: I like this answer :D

Comment: I think the name should be taken at full, just move the space a little bit to the left...

Comment: @Hobbamok Be Ndover?

Comment: Bend Over :D
And yes, I have a dirty mind

Answer (score 3):

Is the code:

> 38076

because

> it spells "globe" when typed into a calculator and turned upside down, and encompassing the whole earth is pretty far outside "the box" (the safe).

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Christoph's answer...

Is the answer:

> 52488

Because:

> The answer is in [Ben Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52488/ben-dover)'s head (*https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/**52488**/ben-dover*)